# How to change the class of a list from array to list?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with names and values that must be converted into a list of vectors. The names determine in which vector each value must be allocated. To automatize the creation of my list, I'm using tapply:

```
d_df <- data.frame(name=c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)),value=LETTERS[1:10])
d_list_auto <- tapply(d_df$value,d_df$name, FUN=as.character)
d_list_auto <- unname(d_list_auto)
d_list_manual <- list(LETTERS[1:5],LETTERS[6:10])
```

For practical effects, d_list_auto and d_list_manual are the same thing, but their classes are different (and the function to which I pass the list complains about it).

```
class(d_list_auto) #array
class(d_list_manual) #list
```

I tried to coerce the class change with as.list() and different flavours of apply functions to no avail:

```
class(as.list(d_list_auto)) #array
apply(d_list_auto,1,as.list) #Creates a list of lists
```

How can I coerce d_list_auto into class list without losing the structure of my data?

**EDIT**

A very nasty solution:

```
class(apply(d_list_auto,1,as.list)) #list
```

Someone has a more elegant suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First let's look at the structures of each object:

```
str(d_list_auto)
# List of 2
#  $ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
#  $ : chr [1:5] "F" "G" "H" "I" ...
#  - attr(*, "dim")= int 2

str(d_list_manual)
# List of 2
#  $ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
#  $ : chr [1:5] "F" "G" "H" "I" ...
```

Looks  like the only difference is that `d_list_auto` has a `dim` attribute, left over from `tapply()`.  We can remove that by assigning `NULL` to as the new dimension.

```
dim(d_list_auto) <- NULL
```

Now let's see if it worked:

```
class(d_list_auto)
# [1] "list"
identical(d_list_auto, d_list_manual)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Manually doing `lapply(split(),...)` might be another option, but I think that will need to be `unname`d to match the output exactly.